# Quantum efficiency and relative response of a photodetector

Tags: electric-circuits, astrophysics, photoelectric-effect

by looking at those two graphs from the same CMOS sensor (Sony IMX 533), one monochromatic and one with a colour filter array (CFA), I was wondering why the monochrome sensor is expressed as absolute quantum efficiency and the color one in relative response. Is the latter related only to the transmission of the RGB filter array or does it include a sort of relative quantum efficiency?

I know that QE is basically the ratio between the effective photo-electrons generated and the number of incident photons, so an adimensional value, while RR can be expressed both as Amp/Watt or Volt/Watt but basically both give an idea of the efficiency of a detector.
Thanks in advance to whoever can answer. [image: Monochrome sensor]

[image: CFA sensor]

Comment: Overall qe is reduced by the absorptive color filters, i.e. some of the green photons will be lost in the green filter etc.   But it is more complex, see this link https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87528/how-much-light-and-resolution-is-lost-to-color-filter-arrays.  BUT look at Orbit's answer which is much better than the first answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the discussion I was looking for!